# I need a dropdown brands filter for Silvershop

Tags: silverstripe, silvershop

How do I filter $Product on AdditionalCategories in the template?

I've tried:

```
$Product.filter('AdditionalCategories', $MyFilter)
```

But there is no AdditionalCategories column on Product in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @3dgoo,

Looks like I needed the following:

```
<% loop $Products.filter('Product_ProductCategories.ProductCategoryID', $MyFilter) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

`Product` has a many to many relationship to `ProductCategory` called [`ProductCategories`](https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-core/blob/master/code/product/Product.php#L41-L43).

If we want to filter products on the category relationship we would call the following:

```
$Product.filter('ProductCategories.ID', 5)
```

I would recommend writing this filter in a function in a controller. Something like this:

```
public function getFilteredProducts() {
    return Product::get()->filter('ProductCategories.Title', 'my-filter');
}
```